# Concatenate some strings in a list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
["i", "'", "ll", "get", "you", "in", "their", "call"]
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
["i'll", "get", "you", "in", "their", "call"]
```

So I need to concatenate words before and after apostrophes.

I tried to do it like this:

```
restored_text = ['i', "'", 'll', 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call']
restored_text_fixed = []
k = 0
i = 0
while i in (x for x in range(len(restored_text)) if k == 0):
    print(i)
    print('k', k)
    if k > 0:
        k = k - 1      
    if restored_text[i+1] == "'" and i > 0:
        restored_text_fixed.append(restored_text[i] + "'" + restored_text[i+2])
        k = 2            
    else:
        restored_text_fixed.append(restored_text[i])
    i += 1
```

But it seems that code doesn't work properly.

Comment: We would prefer for you to describe exactly what's occurring and the exact issue, instead of just saying "that code doesn't work properly".

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iterator from the list and concatenate the current item and the next item from the iterator with the previous item if the current item is an apostrophe:

```
restored_text = ["i", "'", "ll", "get", "you", "in", "their", "call"]
restored_text_fixed = []
i = iter(restored_text)
for s in i:
    if s == "'":
        restored_text_fixed[-1] += s + next(i)
    else:
        restored_text_fixed.append(s)
```

`restored_text_fixed` becomes:

```
["i'll", 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call']
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not work if you have space (`" "`) in one of the elements or if you have apostrophe between two spaces (`` " ` " ``) in the elements, but if this list is a result of some tokenization process you could use this simple approach -

Just join them back with spaces, replace `` " ` " `` with `` "`" `` and split back.

```
a = ["i", "'", "ll", "get", "you", "in", "their", "call"]
" ".join(a).replace(" ' ", "'").split(" ")
> ["i'll", 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call']
```

If you do have spaces but you absolutely sure you don't have other character (e.g. `$`) you can replace spaces with `$` before and then replace them back to spaces afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Something that is a bit more in the flavour of the original post:

```
restored_text = ['i', "'", 'll', 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call']
restored_text_fixed = []

i = 0
while i < len(restored_text):
    # catch situations where there is no next element, otherwise the 
    # next if clause will break the script
    if i == len(restored_text)-1:
        restored_text_fixed.append(restored_text[i])
        break

    if restored_text[i+1] == "'":
        restored_text_fixed.append(restored_text[i] + "'" + restored_text[i+2])
        i += 3

    else:
        restored_text_fixed.append(restored_text[i])
        i += 1

print(restored_text_fixed)
```

Note that the other answers are considered a lot more pythonic, and that this looping over indices can usually be improved. Hopefully this can fix the bugs with your particular use case though

Answer (score 0):

```
restored_text = ["i", "'", "ll", "get", "you", "in", "their", "call"]

#preparing the array "restored_text_fixed" to make expected number of elements 
j = 0
for item in restored_text:
    if item == "'":
    j +=1

j = j * 2 # because each apostrophe took 3 elements from array, like ['i', "'", 'll'] total 3 elements, after it become 1 element ['i'll'] 

restored_text_fixed = ["0" for x in range(len(restored_text)-(j))]

#the processes above to allow us respect the position of elements from old array "restored_text" to new array "restored_text_fixed"


p = 0
for itemPos in range(len(restored_text)):
    if itemPos < len(restored_text)-1 and restored_text[itemPos+1] == "'":
       restored_text_fixed[p] = restored_text[itemPos]+""+ restored_text[itemPos+1]+""+restored_text[itemPos+2]
       p += 1
    elif restored_text[itemPos-1] != "'" and restored_text[itemPos] != "'":
       restored_text_fixed[p] = restored_text[itemPos]
       p += 1


print(restored_text_fixed)


#OUTPUT
#["i'll", 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call', "get'in"]

#NOTE
#restored_text = ['i', "'", 'll', 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call', 'get', "'", 'in'] # add more elements to test if can work from any pos. it work
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following line:

```
>>> l = ["i", "'", "ll", "get", "you", "in", "their", "call"]
>>> "'".join(map(str.strip, ' '.join(l).split("'"))).split()
["i'll", 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call']
```

Breaking it down:

```
l = ' '.join(l)       # join words into sentence => "i ' ll get you in their call"
l = l.split("'")      # split by quotation mark  => ['i ', ' ll get you in their call']
l = map(str.strip, l) # strip off spaces         => ['i', 'll get you in their call']
l = "'".join(l)       # add back quotation mark  => "i'll get you in their call"
l = l.split()         # split back into words    => ["i'll", 'get', 'you', 'in', 'their', 'call']
```

Comment: Note that this will work only if the strings in the list do not contain spaces.